# Deriving time dilation from line element

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time-dilation

I am having trouble deriving the time dilation. I am using $(-, +, +, +)$ sign convention.

For Minkowski metric, the line element is equal to:
$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$

For a motionless ($dx = dy = dz = 0$) distant observer the line element is equal to:
$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2$$

And for a moving object the line element is equal to:
$$ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$
Where $\tau$ is its proper time.

Now, as far as I understand, I need to set these two line elements equal and solve for $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$:
$$-c^2dt^2 = -c^2d\tau^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$
$$\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2 = 1 - \frac{\left(\frac{dx}{d\tau}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{d\tau}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{d\tau}\right)^2}{c^2}$$
$$\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$

This does not make sense to me, since the time measured by the motionless stationary observer $t$ should be greater than the proper time $\tau$. So $\frac{dt}{d\tau} > 1$. This is not true for $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$.
I already saw $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ somewhere, but I'm not sure how to arrive at it.

For Schwarzschild's metric, I am solving this for $\frac{dt}{d\tau}$:
$$-c^2 dt^2 =
-\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)c^2 d\tau^2 + \left(1 - \frac{r_2}{r}\right)^{-1} dr^2 + r^{2} \left(d\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \, d\phi^2\right)$$

Doing this, I arrive at:
$$\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2 =
\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right) - \left(1 - \frac{r_2}{r}\right)^{-1} \frac{1}{c^2} \left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{r}{c}\right)^{2} \left(\left(\frac{d\theta}{d\tau}\right)^2 + \sin^2 \theta \, \left(\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}\right)^2\right)$$
This doesn't seem even close to being correct. I already saw other posts and the equation is very different. I want to have it universal, so I can plug in any values. Where am I making a mistake? Maybe the change in position over a change in time (e.g. $\frac{dx}{d\tau}$) should be with respect to $t$ instead ($\frac{dx}{dt})$?

Comment: Your initial line element is incorrect, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54569/question-about-proper-time-in-general-relativity

Comment: @Eletie I'm sorry, could you point out the mistake to me? I got it from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_element#Minkowskian_spacetime and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)#Flat_spacetime Both say $ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$

Comment: check your second and third equations... they might not be adequately expressed.

Comment: I can't make sense of the third equation or your equating of the ${\rm d}s^2$. I would recommend taking a step back and thinking about what $t$, $s$, and $\tau$ are measuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Minkowski metric, the line element is equal to
$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2. \tag{1}$$
In a rest coordinate system ($dx = dy = dz = 0$) time $t$ is equal to proper time $\tau$
$$ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2.  \tag{2}$$
Equating equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ results in
$$-c^2 d\tau^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2, \tag{2}$$
$$\left(\frac{d\tau}{dt}\right)^2 = 1 - \frac{1}{c^2}\left(\Big(\frac{dx}{dt}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{dy}{dt}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{dz}{dt}\Big)^2\right), \tag{3}$$
and finally in correct equation for the dilatation time
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}. \tag{4}$$

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Is $t$ the time of the motionless clock and $\tau$ the proper time of the moving clock? Or is it the opposite? What are the general steps for any metric?

Comment: @Yachim A clock in a rest frame measures proper time. $t$ is the so-called coordinate time from the right side of eq. (1). Moving is a relative notion. My clock rests other clock moves in reference to me. From the viewpoint of other clock you can say the same. About general steps for any metric I cannot answer you yet. I have to think about first.

Comment: The sign of $1/c^2$ in $(3)$ should be positive (or $t$ and $\tau$ should swap places).

Comment: @KrisWalker You are right!

Comment: @Yachim I have had to correct my equation (3), sorry! Now, you have three correct answers.

Comment: @JanG I looked into it again. Is my understanding correct, that changes in spatial coordinates ($dx, dy, dz$) should be over the coordinate time $t$ and not over proper time $\tau$?

Comment: @Yachim You are right and I have corrected the equation $(3)$. The velocity $v$ is derivative on coordinate time $t$. Do we agree?

Comment: @JanG Yeah, I feel like I understand it a bit more, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in your initial setup.

> For Minkowski metric, the line element is equal to:
> $$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$

That is correct.

> For a motionless ($dx = dy = dz = 0$) distant observer the line element is equal to:
> $$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2$$

That is correct but not relevant. The time dilation formula is not restricted to distant observers. Time dilation is the ratio between coordinate time and proper time for a given clock.

> And for a moving object the line element is equal to:
> $$ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$
> Where $\tau$ is its proper time.

This one is incorrect. The correct expression is $$ds^2 = -c^2d\tau^2 $$

Deriving time dilation is straightforward. You simply start with the line element, substitute this corrected expression, divide both sides by $-c^2 dt^2$ and simplify. The result is $1/\gamma^2$, where $\gamma$ is the time dilation factor.

$$ds^2 = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$$$-c^2d\tau^2  = -c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$$$$\frac{d\tau^2 }{dt^2} = 1 -\frac{ dx^2 }{c^2 dt^2} -\frac{ dy^2 }{c^2 dt^2}-\frac{ dz^2 }{c^2 dt^2}  $$$$\frac{1}{\gamma^2} =1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a frame in which the coordinates are $(t, x, y, z)$. An object moving in this frame will have some trajectory with line element $${\rm d}s^2=-c^2{\rm d}t^2+{\rm d}x^2+{\rm d}y^2+{\rm d}z^2.\tag*{(1)}$$ Now boost to the frame of the object, in which the coordinates are $(t^\prime,x^\prime,y^\prime,z^\prime)$. Since the object is at rest in this frame, we have that ${\rm d}x^\prime={\rm d}y^\prime={\rm d}z^\prime=0$, making the line element $${\rm d}s^2=-c^2{\rm d}{t^\prime}^2.\tag*{(2)}$$ This is an invariant, so we recognize $t^\prime$ as an invariant "proper time" of the object and typically denote it as $\tau$, so that ${\rm d}s^2=-c^2{\rm d}\tau^2$. And since it is an invariant, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal, so we have that $$-c^2{\rm d}\tau^2=-c^2{\rm d}t^2+{\rm d}x^2+{\rm d}y^2+{\rm d}z^2,\tag*{(3)}$$ which is easily rearranged to obtain ${\rm d}t/{\rm d}\tau=1/\sqrt{1-\boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}/c^2}$, where $\boldsymbol{v}={\rm d}\boldsymbol{x}/{\rm d}t$.